# 3 * 8 = 18 in c++

Tags: c++, math

Im getting a slight math error in my program, which is causing problems in the rest of it, and i dont get why it is happening. in this part of the class, i did not overload the operators for built in types (i hope). if i did, please show me where

this function is meant to calculate the least number of bits needed to store a the number, which is stored in a `deque <uint8_t> value` as one value, so 0x123456 will be stored as {0x12, 0x34, 0x56}, and the output to integer.bits() should be 21

```
    // all types here are standard, so i dont know whats going on
    unsigned int bits(){
        unsigned int out = value.size() << 3;
        std::cout << out << " " << value.size() << " " << (value.size() << 3) << std::endl;
        uint8_t top = 128;
        while (!(value.front() & top)){
            out--;
            top >>= 1;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

yet, this part is `cout`ing

```
8 1 8
16 2 16
...

and finally, 
18 3 18
```

http://ideone.com/zLfz2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`3*8` is `24`, and in hex that's `0x18`.  You have `std::hex` scattered about your code...

Comment: Could have been worse - could have been base 3 ;)

Comment: Boost library of the day: [`ios_state`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html).

Comment: <whistle/> you're doing an Integer class there :)

Comment: @larsmans: That sounds like a genuinely useful little library!  Thanks for linking...

Answer (score 2):

Someone has changed your stream to hex and it's printing 24 decimal as 18 hex.